# You're the light in my "deepest" hour

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, lyrics

This is one of the verses in the song *How deep is your love* by Bee Gees.

> I believe in you
>   You know the door to my very soul
>   You're the light in my deepest, darkest hour
>   You're my savior when I fall

In the third line, what does it mean to describe the hour as *deep*?

Comment: Interpreting lyrics is Off Topic, but *deepest* is just another metaphoric usage (as per *darkest*) invoking a sense of *lowest, saddest, most downhearted*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I gotta go now, and I won't be able to reply you right away, but where should I post a question about lyrics say next time I have a question on lyrics?

Comment: Here, by the looks of things. I only get one vote out of five needed to close, and I can't stop anyone else from posting an answer.

Comment: @Theo: The question isn't, "Where do I go to ask a question about lyrics?" The question is more like, "How can I ask a question about lyrics without it being off topic?" You do that by searching beyond the lyric in question, and making the question about more than a single song lyric. Do some research, find some other usages of the phrase in question, and then ask about those usages. Once you find a couple more references to a phrase like "deepest hour" in books to go with the one in a song, then you'll be much more ready to ask a question that's bound to be more accepted.

Comment: As a follow-on, I once heard one of the Beatles remark, "People would come up with all kinds of meanings for our songs. If we liked their interpretation, we'd go along with it." So, avoid asking what a particular song lyric means. However, asking about an English expression found in a song lyric is okay, particularly if that expression is found in other places as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *deepest hour* usually refers to the time of our most dire need, despair, gloom, or despair, although it can have a more positive spin (such as the deepest hour of our relationship).

The phrase is found [several times in books](http://www.google.com/#q=%22DEEPEST+HOUR%22&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=-2OZUZ7rJYbg8wT7oYGwDg&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.eWU&fp=feab5470dd4dfd2c&biw=1185&bih=876), often specifically referring to the deepest hour of need, or the darkest hour of night. You're welcome to peruse the several examples shown there, but I'll list my favorite, from a book called *Chance* published in 1921:

> *The night was getting on to what I may call its deepest hour, the hour most favourable to evil purposes of men's hate, despair or greed*...

As for what it means in the song, as FumbleFingers indicated, we don't usually like to speculate what a songwriter means – for some songs, that can be debated for decades. However, this one isn't very enigmatic; it seems safe to surmise that song is simply saying, "You're there for me when I need you most."